# NextJs insists on displaying images that do not exist, how can I stop this?

Tags: next.js

So using the `<Image>` component I have noticed that when updating an image file, the image in the window won't change on refresh.  What is happening is that it is showing an old image file that had the same name.

NextJS is clearing caching this file as I also went into the GCS bucket and deleted the whole path, however it is still showing the image and I cannot get it to stop showing the image.

It does show as being at the path `"src="/_next/image?url=...huge path name"`. But again, I deleted the file in Google Cloud Storage at this path so nothing exists at the URL it is linking to.

What do I have to change with nextJS to stop it from doing this?

Just to be clear, the images are hosted in Google Cloud Storage, not in the app anywhere.

Comment: Can you check your `next.config.js`. Have you set cache-control for images there?

Comment: I have not, I will look into thatnow

Comment: @TusharShahi. how do you set that, all I can find the documentation is sestting it in props or something

Comment: Have you tried deleting `.next` folder?

Comment: I don't have a .next folder

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#caching-behavior.

Comment: thanks, I just ended up having to use an <img> tag instead of <Image>.  not the solution I wanted but the only one that would work.